# Why are the other chunks of the array being ignored?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
function chunk(arr, size) {
  var newr = [];
  var temp = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
   if (temp.length != size) {
      temp.push(arr[i]);
    } else {
      newr.push(temp);
      temp = [];
    }

  }
  return newr;
}

chunk(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 2);
```

Can someone help me why my code isn't working? It's just displaying the first chunk of array and ignoring the second.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one efficient way of doing it using [**`Array.splice()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice):

```
function chunk(arr, size) {
    var out = [];
    while(arr.length) out.push(arr.splice(0, size));
    return out;
}
```

Calling `chunk(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 2);` will return:

```
[
    ["a", "b"],
    ["c", "d"]
]
```

*Note*: The above method **will** modify the original array that is passed into the function.

Answer (score 0):

**To fix your code, try this**

```
function chunk(arr, size) {
    var newr = [];
    var temp = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        temp.push(arr[i]);

        if(temp.length==size || i==arr.length-1) {
            newr.push(temp);
            temp = [];
        }
    }
    return newr;
}

chunk(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 2); // results in [['a','b'],['c','d']]
chunk(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], 2); // results in [['a','b'],['c','d'],['e']]
```

**Why your previous code doesn't work**

Your condition works well. The last iteration does collect the last chunk `['c','d']` in `temp` correctly but it is not added to the `newr` list. Thus, a little modification to cover this issue is made in my code as shown above.